# Secondary axis labels not working?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graph, charts

Okay so I have a datetime x-axis on an MSChart. I want to plot months below the first of each month and years below the change of a year. Here's what I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rdate.Length -1 ; i++)
{
    if (rdate[i].Day == 01 && set == 0)

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(
       rdate[i].AddDays(-20).ToOADate(), rdate[i].AddDays(20).ToOADate(), 
       Convert.ToString(rdate[i].ToString("MMMM")), 1, LabelMarkStyle.None);
    set = 1;

    if (rdate[i].Day > 01) 
    set = 0;

    i++;

    if (rdate[i].Year > rdate[i-1].Year)

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(
       rdate[i].AddDays(-20).ToOADate(), rdate[i].AddDays(20).ToOADate(), 
       Convert.ToString(rdate[i].ToString("yyyy")), 2, LabelMarkStyle.None);     
}
```

However for some reason this skips some months... The years do not show up at all.

rdate is a datetime array used to populate the x axis.

Here is an example of what my code does:
[image]

As you can see, the labels are behaving unexpectedly. I would also like to show a larger tick mark for these dates, and reduce the number of day labels based upon the date range, but I'm at a loss. Anyone done this sort of thing before?

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a similar issue with MSChart when adding too many labels to the x-axis.  The solution was reduce the number of ticks without losing data.

This approach worked for me but you will have to adapt it to your specific needs.

`dataSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.Auto;`

`dataSeries.Points.AddXY(record.DateTime, value);`

I then determined the min and max dates for the given data to determine the preferred interval, your implementation will vary:

`var totalDays = (maxDate.Value - minDate.Value).TotalDays;`

```
if (totalDays < 60)
    chartArea.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
else if (totalDays < 120)
    chartArea.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks;
else
    chartArea.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
```

Specify the AxisX label format:
In your case you  might have to change the `Format` together with the interval.

```
chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format =  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

Hopefully there are some key parts that will provide value for you but you still have to modify it for your particular needs.

Comment: +1, thanks for chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format, I couldn't find it for the life of me ;-)